# How to make buttons on client side that redirect to a php page with database information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http

I am brand new to programming and I had a unique (I think) question.

I made a MySql database for storing employee records. I am able to submit new employee data to the db and am able to retrieve employee data from the db and display it in an HTML table.

I want to create buttons on the table for each ID#. Each button would redirect you to a different php page and display the employee information associated with the ID# whose button was clicked.

Does anyone know how would I go about doing this?

```
echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="25" cellpadding="2">
      <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>First</td>
          <td>Last</td>
          <td>SIN</td>
          <td>Password</td>
      </tr>';

function loadList() {
include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

try {
  $sqlarray = "SELECT * FROM employee;";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlarray);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $employeeID = $row['id'] . "<br>";
      $employeeFN = $row['firstname'] . "<br>";
      $employeeLN = $row['lastname'] . "<br>";
      $employeeSIN = $row['sin_'] . "<br>";
      $employeePASS = $row['pass_'] . "<br>";

      echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$employeeID.'</td>
                <td>'.$employeeFN.'</td>
                <td>'.$employeeLN.'</td>
                <td>'.$employeeSIN.'</td>
                <td>'.$employeePASS.'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
  }
  else {
    echo "error no data";
  }

} catch (\Exception $e) {
  echo ("error");
}
}
```

Comment: Also I'm sorry if I'm not explaining things correctly, just ask for clarification if need be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mate, welcome in the programming world. You can create a anchor tag which will redirect user to a new php page with employee id in URL. check below code:

```
echo '<tr>
          <td>'.$employeeID.'</td>
          <td>'.$employeeFN.'</td>
          <td>'.$employeeLN.'</td>
          <td>'.$employeeSIN.'</td>
          <td>'.$employeePASS.'</td>
          <td><a href="details.php?id='$employeeID.'>View Details</a></td>              
       </tr>'
```

Here you need to create a new php page with details.php name. There you need to get employee id by GET global variable and need to fetch details from database to show. Check below code:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
$employeeId = $_GET['id'];

$sqlarray = "SELECT * FROM employee where id = '".$employeeId."';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlarray);
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$employeeDetails = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Here $employeeDetails has all data which you can use to render in HTML. But please read little bit about SQL injection before using the same code to avoid crashes. Hope it helps you.

Comment: awesome thanks man! appreciate it. works just fine. also ill look into sql security.

Comment: one more problem actually if you have the time: on my index.php page for some reason it only is loading half of the employee records in the database (it skips by increments of 2) do you know why that would be happening?

Comment: @Robert your code seems fine to me. You need to debug it little bit as check mysqli_num_rows($result) value. It's value should be equal to record count of employee table. Else you can connect with me over Skype: rohit.mittal54. I will be happy to assist you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this by adding `<a></a>` tag

```
echo '<tr>
          <td><a href="show.php?id='$employeeID.'>Show</a></td>
          <td>'.$employeeID.'</td>
          <td>'.$employeeFN.'</td>
          <td>'.$employeeLN.'</td>
          <td>'.$employeeSIN.'</td>
          <td>'.$employeePASS.'</td>
       </tr>';
```

And in show.php page get this id by `$_GET['id']`